# ASP.NET WebForms can you manipulate control values client-side to be used on a postback

Tags: asp.net, sql, webforms, code-injection

Sorry for the title, don't know the easiest way to put it.

I am using ASP.NET vb.net with webforms. I have a dropdownlist control on a page.
Currently when the selected dropdown changes, it postbacks on a button click and does something with the selected value

I am wondering if it is possible (by a hacker etc), to manipulate the values of the drop down or send their changed values in a web-request so that they can be outside the dropdowns defined options server side.

e.g

```
Private Sub testbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles testbutton.Click
   Dim test As String = testdropDown.SelectedItem.Value
   testlabel.text = test
End Sub
```

Can the label be filled with something such as xss, if the selected value is changed outside the defined values by a user.

Or if I was placing that value into a SQL query, and only wanted the options of 1-10, could they change the dropdown value to enter say 25 and have it successfully pass into the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but ASP.NET has in build mechanism to avoid it [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . Even if the value is changed on the client side and and it is not matching with the viewstate it will throw you the exception . I think you are safe in case you do not change any default setting. it is not possible to change the values of the dropdown using client side logic it will throw an exception of of corrupt viewstate in .net because of EnableViewStateMac property.

```
         int val;
         if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["val"]),val){
              //now check the range or custom business logic
              if(val > A1 || val < A2)
                   throw new Applicationexception("Out of range");
              //process here

         }else{
            throw new Applicationexception("Some issue");
         }
```

Comment: What in the case of nothing malicious being passed, like just a value outside of the dropdownlist's bounds. Like 1-10 is valid, and I change it to pass 25 as the value into a query.

Comment: That kind of validation you have to do in the you code. Have a white list of value which is allowed . Please see my updated answer

Comment: Ah Sorry, I don't think you understood me, I understand validation checks like this, my bounds was just a theoretical question. I don't know if you know what I mean too posting a request.querystring answer. Im talking about a dropdownlist, can I manipulate its values clientside like change dropdown value from 1 to 30 and when the postback occurs, it reads it as 30 not 5, or would the server only know it to be 5 and process 5 instead.

Comment: it is not possible it will throw an exception of of corrupt viewstate in .net because of EnableViewStateMac property.

Comment: When I try and do it quickly, with a dropdown, button and label. If i change the dropdown value client side then click the button, it returns the original dropdowns value. No viewstate error. Im yet to try and manipulate server requests yet though.